# how to add css file to maven project + primefaces

Tags: jsf, resources

my css file dosent work.

opera shows me:

```
http://localhost:8080/formularz-web/faces/javax.faces.resource/css/mycss.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

netbens shows me:

```
Warning:   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/mycss.css.
```

its mean my project doesn't see the css file.

in index.xhtml i have:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Kwestionarisz osobowy - rejestracja PAW</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <f:facet name="last">       
            <h:outputStylesheet name="css/mycss.css" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:form styleClass="mycss">
```

i tried put h:outputStylesheet into h:head.

i tried dont use f:facet.

i tried add library="css".

i tried another path to the file:

h:outputStylesheet name="mycss.css" (delete css folder and put css file directly to webapp

h:outputStylesheet name="src/main/webapp/css/mycss.css"

h:outputStylesheet name="#{request.contextPath}/css/mycss.css"

what do i wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF search for resources (js, css, etc) in `/webapp/resources`.
You have to place your css in a directory like this `/webapp/resources/css/mycss.css`. In your xhtml/jsf file:

```
<h:body>
  ..
  <h:outputStylesheet name="mycss.css" library="css" />
```

Comment: Thank you, now works. I have a folder resources but not in the webapp folder. I have him basically in the main folder that contains a webapp. I had to manually do folder resources in the webapp.